# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Failed to allocate a 1224 byte allocation with 349124 free bytes and 340KB until OOM

Tags: android, android-layout

There  is  a  bug in  my  application  which  I  cannot  reproduce  frequently. It  crashes  the app. The  error  seems  to  appear  at  SetContentView() line.

Here is my error code.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1224 byte allocation with 349124 free bytes and 340KB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 131072 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free 12288 bytes)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

The  error  is  when  trying  to  inflate  a  regular  view.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you have a memory leak in your code - that is why you are struggling to reproduce it. So it's not necessarily the inflate that is the issue, it just happens to be aligning with your out of memory exception.

Try and profile your memory usage. The profiler can be found at the bottom of the window.

[image]

After playing in your app for a while (go back and forth between screens, rotate the device, just play around), force a garbage collection (little bin icon) then do a heap dump (square with down arrow).

[image]

If you are using the latest Android Studio it will open the resulting dump for you (this might take a few seconds). Once this opens, it will show you if it suspects a memory leak.

[image]

It is not always SUPER reliable though. So, you could consider using Leak Canary instead - but that does gives false positives. Anyway, once you determined whether you have a leak or not, you can scratch around with the resulting heap data (maybe Google can help here. It is a bit tricky of you have never debugged memory leaks before). However, if it seems you DO NOT have a memory leak, maybe consider the following:

- Are you using a lot or very large images in your app? In this case, they might be eating all your memory, and you need to think of a better way to handle your images (again, Google can help. Its a bit much to explain here).
- Are you doing memory intense tasks? For example a recursive function that goes a bit too far? Consider optimising them or, if not possible, using largeHeap = true in your app Manifest file. DO NOT USE LARGE HEAP as an easy solution! Because it will come back to bite you. Rather fix your code first!!

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I will sure check the possibilities of memory leaking.